# Calculus optimization cone dimensions

Tags: calculus, optimization

How can I determine the dimensions of a cone with surface area 1 and maximal volume?

Comment: This is for a textbook problem; I am just very lost.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Start by writing the equation of the surface area of a cone and setting it equal to 1.

Then isolate either h or r in terms of the other.

Then write the equation for the volume of a cone using only one variable, r or h (substitute in your previously calculated expression for the other).

Maximize that expression using first derivative etc...

Answer (score 0):

$\textit{Hint:}$  Let $\mathscr{l}=\sqrt{r^2+h^2}$, so $S=\pi r^2+\pi r\ell=1$.

Then $r^2+r\ell=\frac{1}{\pi}\implies \ell=\frac{\frac{1}{\pi}-r^2}{r}$, so $V=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h\implies$

$V^2=\frac{\pi^2}{9}r^4h^2=\frac{\pi^2}{9}r^4(\ell^2-r^2)=\frac{\pi^2}{9}r^4\left(\frac{(\frac{1}{\pi}-r^2)^2}{r^2}-r^2\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{9}\left[ r^2(\frac{1}{\pi}-r^2)^2-r^6\right]$ gives

$V^2=\frac{\pi^2}{9}\left[r^2(r^4-\frac{2}{\pi}r^2+\frac{1}{\pi^2})-r^6\right]=\frac{1}{9}\left[-2\pi r^4+r^2\right]$.

(Now differentiate, and set the derivative equal to zero.)